# what is the difference between these two sample size calculation formula?

Tags: sample-size

I see at least two variation when i google sample size calculator
The first one is
[image: formula 1]

with the [example online calculator](https://www.calculator.net/sample-size-calculator.html?type=2&cl2=95&ss2=100&pc2=60&ps2=&x=67&y=15#findci) asking only for confidence level, margin of error, population porportion and population size.

The other sample size formula is this :
[image: formula 2]

With the famous [evan miller](https://www.evanmiller.org/ab-testing/sample-size.html#!20;80;5;5;0) sample size calculator asking for baseline conversion, minimum detectable effect, statistical power and significance level.

why are these two formulas different and are there any more formulas out there?